# Scapy ARP mistake

Tags: python, ip, mac-address, arp

my code right here is supposed to say "ARP who has ("192.168.178.1/24") says 192.168.178.64,
but it does not work for me.
It says "Ether/ARP who has ?? says ??"
Here is the Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import scapy.all as scapy


def scan(ip):
    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
    arp_request_broadcast = broadcast/arp_request
    print(arp_request_broadcast.summary())


scan("192.168.178.1/24")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was fixed. Retry using the development version (on github)