# Scapy library giving error ARP who has ?? says?

Tags: python, scapy, arp

```py
import scapy.all as scapy


def scan(ip):
    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    print(arp_request.summary())
    scapy.ls(arp_request)

scan("10.0.2.0/24")
```

This is giving output

`who has ?? says ??`

instead of

`who has 10.0.2.0/24 says 'myIp'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scapy ARP mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460188/scapy-arp-mistake)

Comment: @Cukic0d I have already installed scapy using pip3 but it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error and found a fix to it. Run these commands

```sh
pip uninstall scapy
pip uninstall scapy-http
pip install scapy==2.4.2
pip install scapy-http==1.8.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue by upgrading scapy to the latest version.

use pip3 to upgrade scapy to its latest version

```
pip3 install --upgrade git+git://github.com/secdev/scapy
```

edit:
the above solution should work well,
incase, if you encounter a warning about python PATH, consider this solution [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58051467/10841074).
but make sure you choose the path suggeted by pip3